# Microsoft Teams Audio not being captured in OBS

Tags: microsoft-teams, obs-studio

I have OBS set to capture my Desktop Audio, however, Microsoft teams is the only program that OBS wont recognize the audio (no sound animation in obs). OBS doesnt capture audio when I am in a Teams meeting. All other programs and any sound coming from my pc get captured in obs

Comment: Recording meetings using a third party app seems like a potentially serious privacy issue.

Comment: i just wanted to record it for work training meetings. I guess the app prevents you from capturing audio during a teams meeting it seems? However, im able to capture audio using zoom.

Comment: No, No, and HECK no. Both of these apps allow recording inside themselves, IF the administrator chooses to allow it. Meetings in zoom are covered by privacy rules, especially work meetings, and you ought to ask your IT organization whether such recordings are allowed, and if they are, use the tools inside the apps to make these recordings.

Answer (score 0):

I use OBS to record Teams meetings and it works perfectly for me on Windows 10.
Of course you have to add the Desktop audio  for others' voice  + your Mic for your voice as audio source to OBS.
Maybe provide more information how you have configured OBS to record.

Answer (score 0):

Some Apps like Microsoft Teams are able to output audio to other outputs that are not the system's default.
When OBS records your screen using a "Display Capture", it also records audio from the system's default audio output (only), but not from all other output devices.

You probably have setup Teams to output the conference audio to a different device (like your head-set for example), while the system's default audio may be your speakers or something else.

To solve this in OBS you can add a new source type "Audio Output Capture" and select the device you use during your calls, this should work without having to change your computer or teams settings. There is also a source type "Application Audio Capture" in OBS that is currently in Beta that might be worth trying out for some cases so you don't have to update OBS settings every time you change your Teams settings.

If this doesn't work, check the basic things like the OBS source is not muted, or try changing your MsTeam's output device here:
https://www.miit.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/teams1.jpg

This problem usually is caused by a user that connects his headset, then Windows detects it and changes the default system output to be the headset (as we would expect), but then the user decides that even though he plugged in a headset he wants to change to listen to the speakers, changing it in Window's bottom right corner, but at the same time he keeps his Teams config to use the headset.

Other users mentioned that Teams already has a recording function that may be regulated by your organization, so I would consider that option. However things are not always simple, Teams recording requires a Microsoft Stream paid plan that has limitations, permission requests may be revoked for many reasons even if you are allowed to record, it is stored in the cloud, and is essentially different in many other ways, compared to OBS that is free, can store files locally or on many other platforms and has many more plugins and more control.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your "Desktop Audio" source captures the right device, and not the random default one.

First, go into Teams Settings and under "Devices" you can see what Speaker teams will use.

[image]

Then, go into OBS, and under Audio mixer select "Desktop Audio" properties.

[image]

On the new window, make sure the device name matches with what you saw on the Teams' audio settings tab.

[image]

This way you will ensure the recorded audio will match the call. To test this, do a test call on the Teams app while OBS is recording.